# How to link the language to the specified text in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I want to add a french language to my website that has both English and German, I managed to add the text FR beside the others, but it didn't get linked to the (/fr) path, but to the main page (/).
this is my code

```
20 = HMENU
20 {
  special = language
  special.value = 0,3,6
  #,6,9
  special.normalWhenNoLanguage = 0
  wrap =
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    noBlur = 1
    NO = 1
    NO {
      linkWrap = | |*| &nbsp;&#124;&nbsp;|
      stdWrap.override = EN || DE || FR || NL
      doNotLinkIt = 1
      stdWrap {
        typolink {
          parameter.data = page:uid
          additionalParams = &L=0 || &L=3 || &L=6 || &L=9
          addQueryString = 1
          addQueryString.exclude = L,id,cHash,no_cache
          addQueryString.method = GET
          useCacheHash = 1
          no_cache = 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.
!(https://image.ibb.co/ev9hH6/aaammm.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your Question corretly: You are Missing the "fr/" part in the URL?

Maybe your RealURL or Cooluri Configuration file must be modified to support the new language.

**Edit**: In your `realurl_conf.php` you should have something like this:

```
  'preVars'     => [
    [
      'GETvar'   => 'L',
      'valueMap' => [
        'en' => '3',
        'fr' => '6',
        'nl' => '9'
      ],
      'noMatch'  => 'bypass'
    ]
  ],
```

Comment: Yes but i couldn't find what to modify in the realUrl nor the cooluri, what would the syntacs looks like for that?

Comment: I have edited my answer with some example for realUrl

Comment: yes i do have these, and i actually managed to have a url /fr working.. but i wanted that to be displayed in the home page, the link doesn't lead to the /fr .. i will post a screenshot

Comment: Is your home page translated? If not the link cannot be created

Comment: yes i translated one element in the homepage. is it maybe something i have to change in the setup.ts file?

Comment: maybe you have limited your `config.linkVars` to your two languages eg. `config.linkVars = L(3|6)`

Comment: couldn't find such thing :/

Comment: is your current page (where you test the menu available in all three languages? (have you created translations?). can you please add the generated HTML-output for your language menu to your question?

Comment: oh sorry that was the problem, i created the translation and now it worked